# .net core 3.1 RDLC Report is not working after deploying linux server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rdlc

Am working .net core 3.1 web api  and generating reports using rdlc on local machine it work properly  but after i deploy on  linux Nginx its throwing  "message": "An error occurred during local report processing."   i  include the files in published  documents and  try to put the approprate file path still not throwing error message.
Any Solution to fix this!

Comment: Check the log files.  Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to database.  Then use the explorer to open log files under management.  The RDLC also has a log file that you can find from the Start Menu : All Apps and locate the SQL Server Report Manager.  There is a shortcut for the log files.

Comment: I have searched a lot threads, RDLC report not support in Linux.